# how to store the checked value from checked box and radio box in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile 
I want to display the value in another page which i get from local storage
It Should been check which is been checked in page1

In HTML5:-

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="content">
         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <form>
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Levels:</legend>
     <input type="checkbox" value="One" name="one" id="checkbox-h-2a" class="custom1">
     <label for="checkbox-h-2a">One</label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="None" name="one" checked="checked" id="checkbox-h-2c" class="custom1">
     <label for="checkbox-h-2c">None</label>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
   </div>
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <form>
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Mode:</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="Two" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="On" checked="checked" class="custom2">
     <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">On</label>
     <input type="radio" name="Two" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="Off" class="custom2">
     <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Off</label>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
   </div>   
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
     <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
  <form>
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Levels:</legend>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2a" id="checkbox-h-2a" class="custom1">
     <label for="checkbox-h-2a">One</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-2c"  id="checkbox-h-2c" class="custom1">
     <label for="checkbox-h-2c">None</label>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
   </div>
   <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <form>
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Mode:</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on"  class="custom2">
     <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Steward</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off" class="custom2">
     <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Guest</label>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
   </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In Jquery:-

```
   function getRadioCheckedValue(radio_name)
    {
        var oRadio = $("input[type='radio']");
            for(var i = 0; i < oRadio.length; i++)
            {
                if(oRadio[i].checked)
                {
                    //return oRadio[i].value;
                    localStorage.setItem("mode", oRadio[i].value);
                }
    }
        return '';
    }

    function showSelectedNames(){
        var count = $("#checkid input:checked").length;
        var str = '';
        for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        if(i == count-1){
              str += $("#checkid input:checked")[i].value;
              localStorage.setItem("level", str);
        }
        else{
             str += $("#checkid input:checked")[i].value+',';
             localStorage.setItem("level", str);
        }
        }
        //alert("You selected----"+str);
    }
```

Now Plz help me out how to set the value in Page 2 which is been checked in Page1

Comment: Look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nng6L/5/)....this will helps you .....

Comment: @SindhuSounderrajan sorry its not a proper answer for me as per my requirment

Comment: you did not try anything ? not a line of js in your code, why is that ?

Comment: @mikakun bcoz i dont nw what to write

Comment: you want to pass checkbox/radio value from page1 to page2?

Comment: @Omar YUP i want to pass the value from one page to another

Comment: is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to store values of checkboxes and radio buttons into an array and then save it to `localStorage`. However, note that `localStorage` doesn't accept arrays, so you need to `JSON.stringify()` before saving it into `localStorage` and then `JSON.parse()` to convert it back into a readable array.

Here is how you can collect values of all checkboxes and radio buttons, store them and then read them on next page.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforehide", "[data-role=page]", function () {
    // variables
    var elements = [],
        id = '',
        value = '';

    // push values of checkboxes and radio buttons into an array
    $("[type=checkbox], [type=radio]", this).each(function () {
        id = $(this)[0].id;
        value = $(this).prop("checked");
        elements.push({
            "id": id,
                "value": value
        });
    });

    // convert array into a string
    // in order store it into localStorage
    localStorage["values"] = JSON.stringify(elements);
});

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "[data-role=page]", function () {
    // active page
    var active = $.mobile.activePage;

    // parse array of checkboxes and radio buttons
    var read_array = JSON.parse(localStorage["values"]);

    // check/uncheck checkboxes and radio buttons
    $.each(read_array, function (e, v) {
        var check_id = "#" + v.id,
            check_value = v.value;
        $(check_id, active).prop("checked", check_value).checkboxradio("refresh");
    });
});
```

**Note:** elements `id` should be the same on other pages.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LCPs5/)**

Comment: In JQM you can't use the same ID twice,  even if they are on two different pages.

Comment: @Drew you can, as long as you specify which page to look for that `id`. that's why I used `$.mobile.activePage`.

Comment: @Omar ur code is working fine but if there is too many page in html5 then in page1 it is been changed and i want to display in page 6 then how it will work

Comment: @Omar how to now the id of the checked box which is been checked because according to that i have to display some pages in html5

Comment: @AtulDhanuka to show result in a specific page use `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page_id", function () {`

Comment: @Omar in checkbox if i wanted to now tht the value of the checked box which is been clicked

Comment: @Omar i tried which value is been clicked but it is coming two type because id is similar i.e., why

Comment: @AtulDhanuka you can also add value(text) of the checked checkbox or radio. I'll update my demo.

Comment: @AtulDhanuka check the same demo in the answer. results are shown when you move to next page.